# fetch() returns opaque when url entered into browser returns expected data

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch

I have a react app which does a fetch to a WebAPI that I wrote.  This is the url for the WebAPI:

```
http://ec2-54-70-8-113.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/api/homepage
```

When I enter the url of the webAPI into a browser, I get back this:

```
<ArrayOfHomepage xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebAPI">
    <Homepage>
        <product_description>
            This application will allow the user to use his/her device camera to scan a product barcode and look up the value of the prodcut on Amazon and eBay based on the products barcode
        </product_description>
        <product_title>What's my crap worth</product_title>
        <return_code>1 - successful read from database</return_code>
    </Homepage>
</ArrayOfHomepage>
```

That is exactly what I expected to receive.  This is the code of my React Fetch():

```
let url = "http://ec2-54-70-8-113.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/api/homepage";

fetch(url, {mode: "no-cors"})
  .then(response => response)
  .then(data => console.log("data: ", data));
```

And this is what is returned:

```
Data:
Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
```

Not what I was expecting.  When I remove the {mode: "no-cors"} parameter from the fetch, I get this error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors'
to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Any suggestion on how to retrieve the data correctly with a fetch?

Thanks for any suggestions or advice.

Comment: `.then(response => response)` does nothing.. did you mean `.then(response => response.text())` ?

Comment: and if the amazon resource doesn't allow cors requests then you won't be able to fetch them from the browser.. you'll need a proxy server to get that data. and last question... why do you want to get XML data on the client?? what are you going to do with that?

Comment: also `fetch` isn't a react thing, it's part of the browser api

Comment: I can get the data from the WebAPI by typing the address of the WebAPI into a browser url box and hitting return.  I can also enter the url into Postman and Pastman is able to retrieve the data.  So I would think I should be able to get the same data back by using the fetch().  I'm just learning so forgive me if I mix my terminology.  The end result of this process is to be able to retrieve the data from the WebAPI and display it on a mobile device.

Comment: You can't receive the data from that domain as the browser correctly tells you because the response did not contain the required header to allow cross origin access. So if you are controlling that server you need to make sure to correctly set the cors header to allow access from other domains. Also see [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: To be precise this is a browser security feature. So you can still get the data with e.g. curl but in browsers that honor CORS you aren't able to access them in your javascript.